# Problems with JavaScript timer

Tags: javascript

I just made a clock (The 100 hour is just testing) in JavaScript. I don't know what is wrong, but it will not work. Can anyone please help?

I have searched everywhere in the code, nothing looks wrong.

```
        var hour,
            minute,
            second;
        hour = 100;
        minute = 0;
        second = 0;

        function changeTime() {
            second--;
            if (second < 0) {
                minute--;
            }
            if (minute < 0) {
                hour--;
            }
if (hour > 0 && minute > 0 && seconds > 0) {
            document.getElementById("clock").innerHTML = hour + ":" + minute + ":" + seconds;
} if (hour > 0 && minute > 0 && seconds = 0) {
        document.getElementById("clock").innerHTML = hour + ":" + minute + ": 00";
} if (hour > 0 && minute = 0 && seconds = 0) {
        document.getElementById("clock").innerHTML = hour + ":00: 00";
} if (hour > 0 && minute = 0 && seconds > 0) {
        document.getElementById("clock").innerHTML = hour + ":00:" + seconds;
} if (hour = 0 && minute > 0 && seconds > 0) {
        document.getElementById("clock").innerHTML = minute + ":" + seconds;
} if (hour = 0 && minute = 0 && seconds > 0) {
        document.getElementById("clock").innerHTML = "0:" + seconds;
} if (hour = 0 && minute > 0 && seconds = 0) {
        document.getElementById("clock").innerHTML = minute + ":00";
} if (hour = 0 && minute = 0 && seconds = 0) {
        document.getElementById("clock").innerHTML = "00:00";
} 
            if (hour = 0 && minute = 0 && second = 0) {
                return;
            } else {
setInterval(changeTime, 50);
            }
        }
```

It should write "100:00:00" to paragraph "clock". It instead writes nothing.

Edit: I put it to change 20 times a second, so that I could see some possibilities easier.

Edit 2: Electric Boogaloo: I fixed it. Thanks to sonyv (and a tweak or two from me.)

Comment: `=` -> `===` ...

Comment: What is kicking off the first call to `changeTime()`?

Comment: Also, where you're referring to your variable `second` as `seconds` throws an error that scuttles the whole thing.

Comment: Ah, shoot. Yeah, I'll fix that...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nothing will be printed with the hour, minute, seconds inputs you provided. I have modified your code and recalling the changeTime() for every 5 seconds. Also, Why you are decreasing seconds at the initial step? Try with the below code:

```
    var hour, minute, seconds;
            hour = 100;
            minute = 1;
            seconds = 1;
    changeTime();
    function changeTime() {
    seconds--;
    if (seconds < 0) {
        minute--;
    }
    if (minute < 0) {
        hour--;
    }

    console.log(hour+" - "+ minute +" - "+ seconds);
    if (hour > 0 && minute > 0 && seconds > 0) {
        document.getElementById("clock").innerHTML = hour + ":" + minute + ":" + seconds;
    }
    else if (hour > 0 && minute > 0 && seconds == 0) {
        document.getElementById("clock").innerHTML = hour + ":" + minute + ": 00";
    }else if (hour > 0 && minute == 0 && seconds == 0) {
        document.getElementById("clock").innerHTML = hour + ":00: 00";
    }else if (hour > 0 && minute == 0 && seconds > 0) {
        document.getElementById("clock").innerHTML = hour + ":00:" + seconds;
    }else if (hour == 0 && minute > 0 && seconds > 0) {
        document.getElementById("clock").innerHTML = minute + ":" + seconds;
    }else if (hour == 0 && minute == 0 && seconds > 0) {
        document.getElementById("clock").innerHTML = "0:" + seconds;
    }else if (hour == 0 && minute > 0 && seconds == 0) {
        document.getElementById("clock").innerHTML = minute + ":00";
    }else if (hour == 0 && minute == 0 && seconds == 0) {
        document.getElementById("clock").innerHTML = "00:00";
    }else{
        document.getElementById("clock").innerHTML = "test";
    } 
    if (hour == 0 && minute == 0 && seconds == 0) {
        return;
    } else {
        setInterval(changeTime, 5000);
    }
}
```

Comment: I made it like that so it would change the time at the beginning, check earlier, and input those values later. Thanks, though.

Comment: Also, this code doesn't seem to work. It shows the time, but doesn't count down

Comment: Nevermind, it does! I just had to make it so that each time the seconds goes down to -1, it changes the seconds value to 59. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

You are assigning 0 to the variable rather than checking it,

Instead of "=" it should be "==" or "==="

"==" Checks the value

"===" Checks the value and type **Recommended**

Try this

```
      var hour,
              minute,
              second;
          hour = 100;
          minute = 0;
          second = 0;

          function changeTime() {
              second--;
              if (second < 0) {
                  minute--;
              }
              if (minute < 0) {
                  hour--;
              }
  if (hour > 0 && minute > 0 && second > 0) {
              document.getElementById("clock").innerHTML = hour + ":" + minute + ":" + second;
  } if (hour > 0 && minute > 0 && second == 0) {
          document.getElementById("clock").innerHTML = hour + ":" + minute + ": 00";
  } if (hour > 0 && minute == 0 && second == 0) {
          document.getElementById("clock").innerHTML = hour + ":00: 00";
  } if (hour > 0 && minute == 0 && second > 0) {
          document.getElementById("clock").innerHTML = hour + ":00:" + second;
  } if (hour == 0 && minute > 0 && second > 0) {
          document.getElementById("clock").innerHTML = minute + ":" + second;
  } if (hour == 0 && minute == 0 && second > 0) {
          document.getElementById("clock").innerHTML = "0:" + second;
  } if (hour == 0 && minute > 0 && second == 0) {
          document.getElementById("clock").innerHTML = minute + ":00";
  } if (hour == 0 && minute == 0 && second == 0) {
          document.getElementById("clock").innerHTML = "00:00";
  }
              if (hour == 0 && minute == 0 && second == 0) {
                  return;
              } else {
  setInterval(changeTime, 50);
              }
          }
```

Comment: It should be `===`. Always. `==` is just bad style

Comment: Yes, I totally agree on that

Comment: This code did work (although I had to fix a few things)

Sonyv also helped. Thanks to both of you!